# Determine the (N-1)th fibonacci number from a given extremely large Nth ?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hi mathgeeks,

Given an extremely large fibonacci number X, and it's position in the fibonacci sequence N, is there any way to determine the N-1th fibo num, WITHOUT doing the bruteforce dance of counting from 1 upwards?

I've tried attacking the problem by dividing the number by two, and determining the difference between the N-1th, and N-2th, but that would require calculating Fib(n-3)/2, which makes the problem circular.

Also would be interested, if this can be proven not to be possible, thanks

Comment: Just divide by the golden mean and round to the nearest integer. This gives the correct (n-1)st Fibonacci provided that F_n is greater than 1. 

Comment: @Todd, that's a very similar approach to the one suggested below by J.C. Ottem.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Anyway, I vote to close this question as being not anywhere near research level. 

Answer (score 5):

For large $n$, $\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n} \approx \phi = 1.618..$. Hence you can get $f_n$ from $f_{n+1}$ by rounding $\frac{f_{n+1}}{\phi}$ to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 1):

The n-th Fibonacci number can be calculated in log n steps, see, e.g., [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~mhock/SSL/fibcalc.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mathgeeks can compute a large fibonacci number without doing any kind of dance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio

Comment: But here the idea is that you *know* one of the numbers and want the previous one. Using Binet's formula in the obvious way forgets that piece of information.